# React Testing with data fetching not resolving promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise

I refer to the following tutorial regarding data fetching on [ReactJS.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching), because I wanted to use it as a template for my own test.

I use `npm test`, which calls react-scripts test, and, as far as i know, uses **jasmine**.

I created the user.js and user.test.js as described in the tutorial.

```js
// user.test.js

import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import User from "./user";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  // setup a DOM element as a render target
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // cleanup on exiting
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

it("renders user data", async () => {
  const fakeUser = {
    name: "Joni Baez",
    age: "32",
    address: "123, Charming Avenue"
  };

  jest.spyOn(global, "fetch").mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      json: () => Promise.resolve(fakeUser)
    })
  );

  // Use the asynchronous version of act to apply resolved promises
  await act(async () => {
    render(<User id="123" />, container);
  });

  expect(container.querySelector("summary").textContent).toBe(fakeUser.name);
  expect(container.querySelector("strong").textContent).toBe(fakeUser.age);
  expect(container.textContent).toContain(fakeUser.address);

  // remove the mock to ensure tests are completely isolated
  global.fetch.mockRestore();
});
```

When I run the test I get `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.
setTimeout.Error`

For some reason, it does not seem to resolve the promise.

What am I doing wrong? I can't believe this tutorial is **bugged**! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Mmm, I created a new project with `create-react-app` and the test seems to be working. Can you provide the `package.json` in your question? In order for `act` to support the async version you must use `react-dom` ^16.9.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. You strictly need react-dom >= 16.9.0